# PowerShell order sensitive Compare-Objects diff

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to do the order comparison of items in arrays with `Compare-Object` aka `diff` in PowerShell? if not, suggest a workaround.

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5)
$b1=@(1,2,3,5,4)
if (Compare-Object $a1 $b1) {
    Write-Host 'Wrong order '
}
else {
    Write-Host 'OK' 
}
```

Comment: can't you use if($a1 -ne $b1) {} in this case? if they are identical?

Comment: can't you easily sort them? `$a1 = $a1 | sort-object` or via get-Enumerator() if you need them sorted?

Comment: And what if they contain different things, but are both sorted in order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-SyncWindow 0`:

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5)
$b1=@(1,2,3,5,4)
if (Compare-Object $a1 $b1 -SyncWindow 0) {
    Write-Host 'Wrong order '
}
else {
    Write-Host 'OK' 
}
```

More info: [Comparing Arrays in Windows PowerShell](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/effective-powershell-item-13-comparing-arrays-in-windows-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

You could compare items in arrays value by value, like this:

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
$b1=@(1,2,3,5,4,6,7,9,8,10)

$i= 0
$counter = 0
$obj = @()

foreach ($a in $a1)
{
    $sub_obj = New-Object PSObject
    $sub_obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Value1 -Value $a      
    $sub_obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Value2 -Value $b1[$i]
    if ($a -eq $b1[$i])
    {
         $sub_obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsMatch -Value $true
    }
    else
    {
        $sub_obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsMatch -Value $false
        $counter++
    }
    $obj += $sub_obj
    $i++
}

Write-Output $obj | Format-Table -AutoSize

if ($counter -gt 0)
{Write-Host 'Wrong order!'}
else
{Write-Host 'Correct order!'}
```

**Output:**

```
Value1 Value2 IsMatch
------ ------ -------
     1      1    True
     2      2    True
     3      3    True
     4      5   False
     5      4   False
     6      6    True
     7      7    True
     8      9   False
     9      8   False
    10     10    True


Wrong order!
```