# powershell get-contain is showing difference form Out-String when comparing Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, string-comparison

I am running one small script to compare the content present on one file with is a response of one command which return the array

```
$data = @('Zero','One','Two','Three')
$file = "C:\test.txt"

# Save the array to file 
Set-Content $file  (Out-String -InputObject $data)

#compair file to array 
$IsIdentical = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (get-content -Path $file) -DifferenceObject (Out-String -InputObject $data)
if($IsIdentical -eq $null)
{
    Write-Output "Identical"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Not Identical"
}
```

I am getting output as `Not Identical`

can someone please explain why getting not identical !!! Also, how can I fix this?

Comment: Use the `-Stream` switch on `Out-String` to prevent the extra blank line at the end of the output.

Comment: You may want to add argument `-syncWindow 0` to `Compare-Object` call. See [PowerShell order sensitive Compare-Objects diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40507552/7571258).

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the response I have tried, still getting `Not Identical`.

Comment: My comment is not a solution for your question, but it shows how to fix another problem. `Compare-Object` match items in any order by default. So `@('Zero','One','Two','Three')` would compare as "equal" to `@('One','Zero','Two','Three')`. By adding `-syncWindow 0` the arrays will only compare equal if order is equal too.

Comment: Is there a blank line in the file?  What is the output of `get-content test.txt`?  Or what does `$IsIdentical` end up being?

Comment: @zett42 compare-object with the default syncwindow can also be very slow for large files.

Answer (score 0):

[Out-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.1) without the `-Stream` processes the entire input object at once. Once that object input is converted to string, a newline character combination is added to the end. When `-Stream` is used, each line of input is processed as a string and the final newline characters are not appended.

Since `Out-String -InputObject $data` produces extra newline characters at the end of the output and `$data` does not have them, the comparison result is expected. You can utilize switches on `Set-Content` or `Out-String` to deal with this behavior.

```
# Option 1 Using -Stream Switch with Out-String
Set-Content $file (Out-String -InputObject $data -Stream)

# Option 2 Using -NoNewLine with Set-Content
Set-Content $file (Out-String -InputObject $data) -NoNewLine

$IsIdentical = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path $file) -DifferenceObject $data
$null -eq $IsIdentical
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but after doing the changed still getting the response `Not Identical` i have tried the option one and two !!! Both returning the  `$IsIdentical` with the same responce