# IndexOf() or .FindIndex() case-insensitive

Tags: powershell, indexing, case-insensitive

I am trying to validate some XML with verbose logging of issues, including required order of attributes and miscapitalization. If the required order of attributes is `one, two, three` and the XML in question has `one, three, two` I want to log it. And if an attributes is simply miscapitalized, say `TWO` instead of `two` I want to log that as well.
Currently I have two arrays, `$ordered` with the names of the attributes as they should be (correct capitalization) and `$miscapitalized` with the names of the miscapitalized attributes.
So, given attributes of `one, three, TWO` and required order of `one, two, three`

`$ordered = one, two, three`

`$miscapitalized = TWO`

From here I want to append the miscapitalizion, so a new variable

`$logged = one, two (TWO), three`

I can get the index of `$ordered` where the miscapitalization occurs with

```
foreach ($attribute in $ordered) {
    if ($attribute -iin $miscapitalized) {
        $indexOrdered = [array]::IndexOf($ordered, $attribute)
    }
}
```

However, I can't get the index in `$miscapitalized` based on the (correctly capitalized) `$attribute`. I tried

```
$miscapitalized = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$miscapitalized.IndexOf('TWO')
```

which doesn't work because `.IndexOf()` is case sensitive. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265128/is-it-possible-to-make-indexof-case-insensitive-in-powershell) that says `[Collections.Generic.List[Object]]` will work, so I thought perhaps Generic.List was where the functionality came from. So I tried

```
$miscapitalized = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@('one', 'two', 'three')
$miscapitalized.FindIndex('TWO')
```

Which throws

> Cannot find an overload for "FindIndex" and the argument count: "1".

That led me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0) that says I need an actual predicate type, not just a string. At which point I am in WAY over my head, and the only thing that I could come up with is `$miscapitalized.FindIndex([System.Predicate]::new('TWO'))` which doesn't work. I suspect a Predicate could/should be a regex somehow, but I can't seem to find anything that points me in the right direction, or at least that I can understand and recognize that it is pointing me in the right direction. I also found `https://www.powershellstation.com/2010/05/18/passing-predicates-as-parameters-in-powershell/` that talks about a code block as predicate, but I am not clear that it's the same usage of the term predicate (it is a widely used term) nor can I grok how to even make a code block that would be helpful here.

I did come up with this approach, which uses the same `foreach` search in `$miscapitalized` as in `$ordered` and it does work. But I wonder if there is a more graceful approach that doesn't require nested loops. Plus, understanding Predicate as it applies here seems useful, as well as (possibly) how a codeblock might be used.

```
$ordered = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$miscapitalized = @('TWO')
$replacements = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]::new()
foreach ($orderedAttribute in $ordered) { 
    if ($orderedAttribute -iin $miscapitalized) {
        $indexOrdered = [array]::IndexOf($ordered, $orderedAttribute)

        foreach ($miscapitalizedAttribute in $miscapitalized) {
            if (($miscapitalizedAttribute -iin $ordered) -and ($miscapitalizedAttribute -ieq $orderedAttribute) -and ($miscapitalizedAttribute -cne $orderedAttribute)) {
                #$indexMiscapitalized = [array]::IndexOf($miscapitalized, $miscapitalizedAttribute)
                $replacements.Add($indexOrdered, "$orderedAttribute ($miscapitalizedAttribute)")
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($replacements.Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($index in $replacements.Keys) {
        $ordered[$index] = $replacements.$index
    }
}

$ordered
```

EDIT: Based on comments below, I have tried this

```
$ordered = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$miscapitalized = @('TWO', 'Three')
$replacements = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]::new()
foreach ($orderedAttribute in $ordered) { 
    if ($orderedAttribute -iin $miscapitalized) {
        $indexOrdered = [array]::IndexOf($ordered, $orderedAttribute)
        if ($indexMiscapitalized = $miscapitalized.FindIndex({param($s) $s -eq $orderedAttribute})) {
            $replacements.Add($indexOrdered, "$orderedAttribute ($($miscapitalized[$indexMiscapitalized]))")
        }
    }
}
if ($replacements.Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($index in $replacements.Keys) {
        $ordered[$index] = $replacements.$index
    }
}

$ordered
```

Which gets the last one (three/Three) but is missing two/TWO. But lots of possible solutions to try tomorrow, since there will be something to learn from each one.

Comment: I didn't read your entire question because I'm lazy (so there may be ways to redo the entire approach), but the predicate problem is solved by passing a block with parameters: `$miscapitalized.FindIndex({param($s) $s -eq 'TWO'})`. PowerShell automatically converts this to a delegate. (`-eq` will still not compare things in a case-sensitive manner; if you want that use an appropiate overload of `String.Equals`, e.g. `$s.Equals("TWO", "Ordinal")`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substitute a scriptblock for the predicate required by `FindIndex()`:

```
PS ~> $miscapitalized = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@('one', 'two', 'three')
PS ~> $predicate = {param($s) $s -eq 'TWO'}
PS ~> $miscapitalized.FindIndex($predicate)
1
```

This will work as expected since PowerShell's `-eq` operator is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I tried to expand on this idea to get multiple miscapitalized attributes, and it is partially working. Edited the OP to show that attempt too.

Comment: @Gordon `if($indexMiscapitalized = $miscapitalized.FindIndex(...)){ ... }` fails because for the `TWO` the resulting value is `0`, which evaluates to `$false`. Change to: `if(($indexMiscapitalized = $miscapitalized.FindIndex(...)) -ge 0){ ... }` (we want to check that the return value is above `-1`, which is what `FindIndex()` returns when no index satisfies the predicate)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you're overthinking this. You could use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to do all the hard work and then you can inspect results and log them accordingly:

```
# Reference array for attributes order and capitalization
[array]$reference = @(
    'one'
    'two'
    'three'
    'four'
)

# Example XML
[xml]$xml = '<foo one="1" oNe="oNe" thrEE="thrEE" two="2">dummy</foo>'

# Compare XML attributes to refrerence array
# -SyncWindow 0 - Order of items in the array matters
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507552/powershell-order-sensitive-compare-objects-diff

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $xml.foo.Attributes.Name -SyncWindow 0 -CaseSensitive -includeEqual
```

This will produce:

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
one         ==
oNe         =>
two         <=
thrEE       =>
three       <=
two         =>
four        <=
```

As you can see, the `one` attribute is in at the correct index (`==`) and properly cased. We also have additional `oNe` attribute, that is out of place.

You could also group the `Compare-Object` result and produce hashtable, which you can use for advanced logging. You could do all kinds of lookups and comparisons using `SideIndicator` and `InputObject` properties.

```
$group = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $xml.foo.Attributes.Name -SyncWindow 0 -CaseSensitive -includeEqual |
Group-Object -Property InputObject -AsHashTable -AsString

$group
```

Result

```
four  {@{InputObject=four; SideIndicator=<=}}
one   {@{InputObject=one; SideIndicator===}, @{InputObject=oNe; SideIndicator==>}}
thrEE {@{InputObject=thrEE; SideIndicator==>}, @{InputObject=three; SideIndicator=<=}}
two   {@{InputObject=two; SideIndicator=<=}, @{InputObject=two; SideIndicator==>}}
```

In this case hashtable keys will be case-insensitive, so you can do stuff like this:

```
foreach ($r in $reference) {
    $ret = $group.$r | Where-Object {
        $_.SideIndicator -ne '==' -and $_.InputObject -cne $r
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    ForEach-Object {
        'Index of {0}: {1}' -f $_, $xml.foo.Attributes.Name.IndexOf($_)
    }

    if ($ret) {
        @{ $r = $ret }
    }
}

Name  Value              
----  -----              
one   Index of "oNe": 1  
three Index of "thrEE": 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a small helper function that finds the index case-insensitive:

```
function Find-Index {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Array,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Value
    )
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Array.Count; $i++) {
        if ($Array[$i] -eq $Value) { return $i }
    }
    -1

    # or combine the elements with some unlikely string
    # convert that to lowercase and split on the same unlikely string
    # then use regular IndexOf() against the value which is also lower-cased:
    # (($Array -join '~@~').ToLowerInvariant() -split '~@~').IndexOf($Value.ToLowerInvariant())
}
```

Then below that, use it like this:

```
# if any of the below arrays has only one item, wrap it inside @()
$ordered        = 'one','two','three'
$miscapitalized = 'One','TWO'

$logged = foreach ($item in $ordered) {
    $index = Find-Index $miscapitalized $item
    if ($index -ge 0) { 
        '{0} ({1})' -f $item, $miscapitalized[$index] 
    }
    else { $item }
}

$logged -join ','
```

Output

```
one (One),two (TWO),three
```